# extract all the numbers from a string in a javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want all the proper natural numbers from a given string,

```
var a = "@1234abc 12 34 5 67 sta5ck over @ numbrs ."
numbers = a.match(/d+/gi)
```

in the above string I should only match the numbers 12, 34, 5, 67, not 1234 from the first word 5 etc..

so numbers should be equal to [12,34,5,67]

Comment: Why should it? `\d+` matches one or more numbers, and `1234` is one or more.

Comment: You're using the wrong sort of slashes around your regex; it should be `/\d+/gi`

Comment: I know its not the correct regex expression, I tried various things but can't think of the right expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use word boundaries,

```
> var a = "@1234abc 12 34 5 67 sta5ck over @ numbrs ."
undefined
> numbers = a.match(/\b\d+\b/g)
[ '12', '34', '5', '67' ]
```

**Explanation:**

- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word charcter(`\w`) and a non-word charcter(`\W`).
- `\d+` One or more numbers.
- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word charcter and a non-word charcter.

**OR**

```
> var myString = '@1234abc 12 34 5 67 sta5ck over @ numbrs .';
undefined
> var myRegEx = /(?:^| )(\d+)(?= |$)/g;
undefined
> function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
...     index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
...     var matches = [];
...     var match;
...     while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
.....         matches.push(match[index]);
.....     }
...     return matches;
... }
undefined
> var matches = getMatches(myString, myRegEx, 1);
undefined
> matches
[ '12', '34', '5', '67' ]
```

Code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/3297613).

Comment: oh \b represents all the spaces?

Comment: Is the first `\b` needed?

Comment: @syllogismos no, it is a zero-width match between word and non-word characters (in any order), see http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html. @j08691 - it is needed as long as you don't want to match `123` from `something123`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj surely you meant "other than `[A-Za-z0-9_]`"

Comment: @j08691 -- it works on `var a` without the first `\b` doesn't it? but if you change `a` to `"@1234 12 34 5 67 sta5ck over @ numbrs ."` then it won't work without first `\b`

Comment: I don't think that there's any need for a case-insensitive match here.

Comment: @yitwail it won't work on `"@1234"` in any case, in the sense that it will match `1234` from that string regardless of first `\b` because there is a word boundary between `@1`. but javascript doesn't support lookbehind, so a nasty hack would be necessary to exclude that case

Comment: @Aprillion \w stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Source http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj my point exactly. you said something completely different which would make this answer incorrect if your statement were true (you implied that `[0-9]` are non-word characters)

Comment: @Aprillion sorry i forget to include `0-9` .

Comment: @Aprillion -- right you are. I should have tested before adding my comment.

Comment: getMatches function doesnt match 1234 in `@1234` where as the first solution matches 1234 in `@1234`

Comment: yes, because @ is a non-word charcter, word boundary exits between the `@` and the number 1. So `\b\d+\b` match 1234 in `@1234` but the second one matches the numbers only if the preceding character must be a line start or space and the following character must be a line end or space. I think now you understand the differences.

Comment: when I directly put the myRegex in the String.match function it is matching an extra space along with the number, but the function getMatches doesn't do that

Comment: Yes .get matches func was defined to print the first captured group only.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested in a proper regex solution to match digits surrounded by space characters, it is simple for languages that support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (like Perl and Python, but not JavaScript at the time of writing):

```
(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization] 
[Debuggex PCRE Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bK-k1TzU4Q7CDW68)

As illustrated in the accepted answer, in languages that don't support lookbehind, it is necessary to use a hack, e.g. to include the 1st space in the match, while keepting the important stuff in a capturing group:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+)(?=\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization] [Debuggex JavaScript Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qA_vc-iFGaOUzoMG)

Then you just need to extract that capturing group from the matches, see e.g. this answer to [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/1176601)

Comment: why did you edit the javascript one out, can you leave it there?

Comment: it's duplicated with @Avinash's answer which you accepted. but I put it back.